# Who presented the articles to the Senate alongside the Clerk?

Tags: united-states, senate, trump-impeachment, house-of-representatives

During the preceding, the Clerk of the House and the Sergeant at Arms of the House were side-by-side. However, during the presentation, the Clerk was next to someone else, seen on the right below. Who is that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you and Up-In-Air noted, the Clerk of the House, Cheryl Johnson, is on the left. The woman to her right is the U.S. Senate Secretary for the Majority, [Laura Dove](https://www.senate.gov/reference/common/person/dove_laura.htm).

Answer (score 1):

She is recognized as the [Clerk of the House](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/politics-news/pelosi-calls-witnesses-trump-trial-after-new-evidence-n1116091) Cheryl Johnson who carried the articles of Impeachment to Senate followed by House Impeachment Managers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! My question identifies the Clerk and asks who she was next to, though